# Debug flow fault message in apex

Tags: visual-workflow, debugging

I need to debug a Flow's Fault Message in Apex. I have a Wait Element in my flow that is failing, but the only error I am receiving is "execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FlowException: The (Wait) element in your flow has validation errors.: (System Code)".

Am I able to debug the Fault Message if it is happening on a Wait Element?

[image]

Comment: Whats in your wait element?

Comment: @Mahmood the wait element is waiting 10 days after the date specified on a date field called "Date_Achieved__c".

Comment: Did you get the email with error details?

Comment: @Mahmood no I did not. No email was sent to me regarding this error.

Comment: Can you please share few screenshots of the configurattion and setup of the flow by editing your question?

Comment: @Mahmood I just added the screenshot to the main question